# Interface between Silicon and Germanium

Tags: material-science

I have a Silicon-Germanium nanowire at hand which I want to calculate its total resistivity. The wire is such that we have the materials stacked alternatingly. i.e. like Si Ge Si Ge Si Ge ...

I have figured out the way which is to calculate the conductance and then finding 1 over that value. however I should take one unit of the material before applying the equations I found. I can either take (Si Ge) as one unit of the wire and use it to calculate the resistivity of the whole, or I can take (Si Ge Si) and do the same. The difference would be that I considered the interface between Si and Ge to be different than the interface between Ge and Si.

I am aware that which method to use is still in dispute however can someone please explain the argument behind which method would most likely be the better one?

In other words, do you think the interface between Si Ge is the same as that between Ge Si?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the interface between n-type Si and Ge, due to Fermi level pinning by interface states, usually an electron depletion zone and possibly a hole inversion layer forms with lateral thicknesses on the order of at least 10nm. Therefore, for a  nanowire you cannot use the bulk material conductivities to calculate the resistance of the wire. Also the interfaces Si/Ge and Ge/Si should be the same in this case.